# How to customize user dialog in botpress ver 11.9.5?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, chatbot, botpress

I am trying to add timestamp to every dialog in botpress chat. So far I am able to add this timestamp in bot's dialog, but I need some pointers in adding the same to user's dialog and choice skill.

Screenshot from chat showing timestamp in bot's dialog
[image]
Custom component

```
export class InfaText extends React.Component {
  message = this.props.text

  getTimestamp = () => {
    let date = new Date();
    let options = {
      month: "short",
      day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
    };
    return date.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options);
  }
  render() {
    return (<div className="infaTextMain">
      <p className="infaTextMessage">{this.message}</p>
      <small className="infaTextTimestamp">{this.getTimestamp()}</small>
    </div>)
  }
}
```

Note: Botpress v11.9.5

Also, is there a generic way to add a timestamp to all dialogs?
**Update**

I followed exactly as stated by @eff_it

I copied **MessageWrapper** & **MySuperOverride** functions to `modules\infa-module\src\views\lite\index.jsx` 
[image]

Then added below snippet under overrides of `modules\channel-web\src\views\full\index.tsx` file

```
{
          module: 'infa-module',
          component: 'MySuperOverride'
}
```

[image]

Still no effect, @eff_it please have a look and suggest is it something that is missing here?

[image]

Comment: I have a similar requirement, did you find anything?

Answer (score 3):

have you tried in BP 12 ? custom components are now much easier to achieve.

You can wrap every messages using the `setMessageWrapper` of the botpressWebchat store, but to do so, you will need to use the overrides property when you initialize the webchat with another custom component (that won't render anything but would use the webchat store). Here is an example views/lite/index.jsx

```
export const MessageWrapper = props => (
  <div>
    <p style={{ color: 'blue' }}>sent on: {new Date(props.sentOn).toDateString()}</p>
    <div style={{ background: 'black', color: 'white' }}>{props.children}</div>
  </div>
)

export const MySuperOverride = props => {
    props.store.setMessageWrapper({ module: 'yourModule', component: 'MessageWrapper' })
    return null
}
```

Then when you initialize the botpressWebchat you can simply use the overrides api as follows

```
window.botpressWebChat.init({
  overrides: {
    before_container: {
      module: 'yourModule',
      component: 'MySuperOverride'
    }
  }
})
```

Refer to the [docs](https://botpress.io/docs/channels/web/#creating-a-custom-component), there is more information on custom components and custom modules. Here is the resulting rendering:

[image: botpress custom component rendering]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did exactly what is mentioned in your answer but still I do not see anything similar to your screenshot.
Updated my question accordingly